# Permanently change per-process stack size

Tags: limit, ulimit

When I use `ulimit -s` to change the per-process stack size, it only lasts for that login; if I restart the setting is lost. How can I permanently change the maximum stack size on my system?

Comment: You need to be clearer about what you have tried and how you verify that it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not posting an answer because I'm not sure what your question is, but it seems like [limits.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/limits.conf.5.html) is what you need.

Comment: @phunehehe - But when i am changing limits.conf but values are not getting affected by process. so please provide me better solution.

Comment: After changing `limits.conf`, you need to get the affected user log out and log in again. A simple reboot will be enough.

Comment: @phunehehe - Thanks for your valuable reply but i have also tried that when i reboot machine then also limits.conf not getting affected.